# How can I prevent staining of adjacent concrete when etching my garage slab?

Tags: concrete, epoxy

I plan to etch my garage floor with citric acid. I am concerned that once rinsed, the citric acid will change the color of the common area driveway outside my garage. I live in a condo, and the drainage is poor, and has a 60 foot run to the drain.  One suggestion was to use a wet/dry vacuum to suck up the citric acid from my garage floor and discard in my tub drain (diluted with water), and then rinse out my garage with water.

Is there a better way to do this? Should I neutralize the citric acid solution on my garage floor with ammonia and then hose out my garage? Citric acid PH is listed at a 3-6 range.  Ammonia PH is 11-12 undiluted. If before applying, I dilute ammonia with water 50/50, that should get me a PH of about 9. Is this advisable, or will there be dangerous fumes from applying this solution to the citric acid covered floor?

Comment: pH isn't linear where you can get halfway to 7 by diluting with 50% water. It's logarithmic.

Comment: Flushing ammonium citrate down a storm drain sounds like bad manners at the very least. Maybe in your quantity it's no big deal, though. See https://www.nj.gov/health/eoh/rtkweb/documents/fs/0096.pdf.

Comment: If you're trying to neutralize, you probably want to predetermine how many oz of ammonia you need to neutralize X oz of citric acid (test strips?).  So if you need Y oz of ammonia to neutralize X oz of acid, and you use 5X oz of acid, you'd want to apply 5Y oz of ammonia before rinsing.

Answer (score 1):

Two things: Wet and quick.

If you add sufficient water to the scene, then quickly and thoroughly flush it across the driveway, it's not going to have enough time to have an impact.

Do take environmental concerns into consideration. A storm drain isn't a trash disposal. It's essentially part of our waterways. The soil to the side of the driveway might be better, where at least some leaching action can be done.